# ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax while trying to create a trigger

Tags: mysql

```
 create
 definer ='root'.'localhost'
 trigger 'maria'.'profesori'
 before insert on 'maria'.'profesori'
 for each row
 begin
 declare mesaj varchar (150);
 if new.nume='Tudor' then
 set mesaj='eroare';
 signal sqlstate'4500' set message_text=mesaj;
 end if;
 end $$;'
```

But I keep receiving this error message:

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ';
>   create
>   definer ='root'.'localhost'
>   trigger 'maria'.'profesori'
>   before insert o' at line 1

Comment: I think the problem is before this. The error message shows a `;` before `create`.

Comment: You probably forgot to put `$$` after the statement before it.

Comment: before create I have mysql> use maria
Database changed
mysql> delimiter $$
mysql> use maria $$
Database changed
Is it something missing?

Comment: I don't know what to tell you, the error message shows a `;` character. I don't know where it's coming from.

Comment: Have you tried removing the `;` after the `$$`?

Comment: `'root'.'localhost'` should be `'root'@'localhost'`

Comment: And you should use backticks, not single quotes around database, trigger, and table names.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
create
 definer ='root'@'localhost'
 trigger `maria`.`profesori`
 before insert on `maria`.`profesori`
 for each row
 begin
 declare mesaj varchar (150);
 if new.nume='Tudor' then
 set mesaj='eroare';
 signal sqlstate'4500' set message_text=mesaj;
 end if;
 end $$
```

1. The definer should be in the form `user@host`, not `user.host`.
2. Database, trigger, and table names should be quoted with backticks, not single quotes (or not quoted at all -- this is only needed if they are reserved words or contain special characters).
3. The `;` after `$$` could be a problem.

Answer (score -2):

change :
signal sqlstate'4500' set message_text=mesaj;
to this :
signal sqlstate'45000' set message_text=mesaj;